# Why <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> should not be placed at the very top?

Tags: html, xml, xhtml, utf-8

Please explain me what are the problems (if any), by putting the following declaration at the very top of the HTML page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: someone care to explain the downvotes on both answers? Are they incorrect?

Comment: I don't see anything incorrect in any of the answers below, myself. There is some opinion in those two which I guess others disagree with. I made comments myself to the opinion in that other answer, but whoever downvoted my answer hasn't done the same.

Comment: @Thilo - Paul's answer is correct. Sander's is mostly wrong. Only setting the content-type will cause the kind of behaviour he describes. The correctness of Andrew's answer requires quite a long explanation of parsers and content-types but on the whole, the line causes more harm than good and it's simply better to leave it out.

Comment: Leaving it out on PHP pages that serve iso-8859-1 or windows-1252, as an example, causes a lot of pain - that (apparently including present company) many people have no clue the source of. PHP still does not properly support UTF-8

Comment: @Andrew - There are various ways to set the charset. The xml declaration is the worst. If you have a server side language like PHP available, I strongly recommend setting it directly in the HTTP headers. This will work cross-browser and regardless of the content-type used.

Comment: We could go back and forth forever, I suppose. But for some people, they can't alter the HTTP headers (some shared hosting, for example). That declaration exists for a reason. That's why my answer starts with, "*If used...*". I think one possible nuance to MISS_DUKE's question that people aren't considering is maybe she's really asking, "Does it need to be **at the top**..."

Comment: I'll leave the nuances of the question to MISS_DUKE to clarify. The declaration exists for a reason - in XML - where there's no guarantee that there is a meta language like HTTP to convey the character set information. That doesn't apply when serving web pages.

Answer (score 5):

Its not good because it will cause IE6 to go into quirks mode.

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200904/using_an_xml_declaration_triggers_quirks_mode_in_ie_6/

And if you've ever worked with IE6 in quirks mode you would know what a painful experience that is.

Comment: Or IE6 in any mode.  /me goes off to cry

Comment: By now, you should be sending everyone with IE6 to http://www.abetterbrowser.org/ because life's too short to support IE6.

Comment: I still get for some of my websites about 20-30% IE6 traffic (and thats with 10-20k uniques a day). So its not worth it for a LOT of people. @Andrew Barber - It doesn't benefit any other browser for having it, and it harms IE for doing it. I see no reason to include it.

Comment: I agree with Paul. Although it's quite sad that we still have to build websites for IE6, it is do-able if you make the right choices. And it's certainly worth it. On my company's shops there are placed about 2000 orders a day, and about 5% of them is placed with IE6. That's thousands of euro's turned over each day by IE6 users. Besides, these people often don't have a choice, because of other software depending on it and being in office environments where they don't even have rights to install other browsers.

Comment: @Andrew Barber: If your content is not UTF-8, you chould certainly not put an XML header at the top that says it is. ;-)

Comment: Obviously, you would put the *correct* content encoding in the declaration. Well, *I* would...

Comment: @Andrew Barber If you're parsing HTML with a raw XML parser you're insane. The amount of errors that end up in average HTML that a XML parser will die on is insane. There's a reason there are better libraries (like HTML agility pack for C#/.NET) for parsing HTML which aren't so limited.

Comment: I didn't say *I* am parsing HTML.

Comment: This is with regards to HTML, as noted in the question. Which is why I said not to include it, this is for browsers and not xml parsers.

Comment: What do you do when you are serving iso-8859-1 or windows-1252 because you are using PHP, which still does not support Unicode properly?

Comment: There are HTML meta tags to put in the header to specify the encoding type. http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/charset.html.en

Answer (score 1):

If used, it *should* be placed at the top. In fact, if it's needed, it pretty much must be placed at the top in order for the rest of the document to be read properly.

It's not needed if your document is UTF-8 or UTF-16. But if otherwise, you should use it. My opinion is you should use it anyway.

The only reason not to use it would be for IE6 users, as IE6 will go into 'quirks mode' if you have that declaration.

But honestly... IE6 *is* a quirk mode anymore.

Don't potentially mess up other more modern parsers for the benefit of an old one.

Comment: As an example: leaving it out on PHP pages that serve iso-8859-1 or windows-1252, as an example, causes a lot of pain - that (apparently including present company) many people have no clue the source of. PHP still does not properly support UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

You can put it on the very top, but you should be aware of the consequences.

- Some (older) browsers will try to download your page instead of display it
- In some browsers, if your XHTML code has an error, it will not try to display it "best effort" like in HTML. Instead, you will get a cryptic XML error.

Also, if you are using XML/XHTML, please make sure you send the right content-type header as well (e.g. application/xml instead of text/html).